# first print all numbers in given sequence, then all characters and other symbols using Array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

How to print first all the numbers in given sequence, then all the characters and letters
using only an array and not a string in C++ ???

For Example

```
intput: 5 (size of array) --> a 1 2 r 4

output: 1 2 4 a r

input: 10 --> a s d @ # $ 7 8 9 1 0

output: 7 8 9 1 0 a s d @ # $
```

```
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    int n, c, j = 0, m = 0, a = 0;
    char arr[1000];
        std::cin >> n; 
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            {
                std::cin >> arr[i];
                std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
            }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean digits saying numbers?

Comment: Note: Look into the staggering array of helper functions at your disposal as part of the Standard Library. Examples [`isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) and [`isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha). Pay special arttention to the notes. Don't try to roll your own because every now and then you come across a system where the alphabet isn't in order, making test like `ch >= 'a' && ch <='z'` fail hilariously. As in "Ha ha ha. So funny. Thanks, <expletive deleted>s."

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to stick with `for` loops for now, just clean up your code by using some helpers from the [cctype](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cctype) header:

```
#include <cctype>

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (std::isdigit(arr[i]))
        std::cout << (char)arr[i] << ' ';
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (std::isalpha(arr[i]))
        std::cout << (char)arr[i] << ' ';
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (!std::isdigit(arr[i]) && !std::isalpha(arr[i]))
        std::cout << (char)arr[i] << ' ';
}
```

This code definitely isn't optimal though, as you can see by the others' more elegant solutions with `std::partition`. Once you gain more confidence in your skills, consider trying out an algorithmic approach: the standard library has [many options](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm). `std::partition` does work well here, but you could also try a sort or remove algorithm instead. All these functions need are the range of your data (in your case, `&arr[0]` or `arr` is the start of the range, and `arr + n` is the end), and usually some function to specify how you want your data partitioned, sorted, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could first [partition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition) the array to place all the digits at the beginning:

```
auto nums = std::stable_partition(arr, arr + n, 
                                  [](unsigned char c) { return std::isdigit(c); });
```

and then partition the remaining part of the array to get the characters:

```
std::stable_partition(nums, arr + n, 
                      [](unsigned char c) { return std::isalpha(c); });
```

and then just print everything out:

```
std::copy(arr, arr + n, std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, " "));
```

Comment: I need to solve the problem in a simple way because I'm a beginner in C++ ))

Comment: It may not seem like it at the moment, but using algorithms *is* the simplest way to solve these problems. Follow the link in the answer, and look at some examples. Once you understand what the algorithm does, it'll seem obvious. Focus on the `partition` first, don't worry too much about the `copy`.

Comment: There just might still be car mechanics out there who prefer "duct tape only" solutions instead of dealing with bolts, screws, screw drivers, wrenches and blow torches ;) They like it simple.

Comment: @BitTickler Yeah, definitely, I work with some of them ;) But I've never actually met a person who learned algorithms *first*, but then prefers raw loops, so I'm happy to put the OP on the right path :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you mean the following. That is the assignment can be easy done using the standard algorithm std::partition applied two timed to the entered sequence. Ot if you want to keep the order of symbols in the same category that you can use the algorithm `std::stable_partition`. Just substitute `std::partition` for `std::stable_partition` in the program below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cctype>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 1000;
    char a[N];
    
    size_t n = 0;
    
    std::cin >> n;
    
    if ( N < n ) n = N;
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        std::cin >> a[i];
    }
    
    auto it = std::partition( a, a + n, []( unsigned char c ){ return ::isdigit( c ); } );
    std::partition( it, a + n, []( unsigned char c ){ return ::isalpha( c ); } );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << a[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

If to enter the sequence

```
10
a s d @ # $ 7 8 9 1 0
```

then the program output will be

```
1 9 8 7 a s d @ $ #
```

Here is the same program but with using std::stable_partition.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cctype>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 1000;
    char a[N];
    
    size_t n = 0;
    
    std::cin >> n;
    
    if ( N < n ) n = N;
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        std::cin >> a[i];
    }
    
    auto it = std::stable_partition( a, a + n, []( unsigned char c ){ return ::isdigit( c ); } );
    std::stable_partition( it, a + n, []( unsigned char c ){ return ::isalpha( c ); } );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << a[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output for the same input sequence will look like

```
7 8 9 1 a s d @ # $
```

Comment: Try an ``e`` as input. I remember on applesoft basic on apple][, it went through as a number, short for ``1.0E0`` ;) But with ``std::is_digit()``, this should not happen here.

Answer (score 0):

````
     ```
       #include <iostream>
       int main() {
       int n, c, j = 0, m = 0, a = 0;
       char A[1000], B[1000], C[1000];
       std::cin >> n;

       for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
        {
            std::cin >> A[i];
        }

       for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            if(A[i] >= '0' && A[i] <= '9')
             {
               B[j] = A[i];
               j++; 
               c = j;
              }    
            else 
            {
               C[m] = A[i];
               m++;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
    {
      A[i] = B[i];
      }
        for (int i = c; i < n; ++i) 
    {
      A[i] = C[a];
      a++;
    }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
     std::cout << A[i] << " ";   
    }
````

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    int n;
    int arr[1000];
    std::cin >> n; 
    int t[1000];
    int count=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            char temp;
            cin>>temp;
            if((int(temp)>=91 && int(temp)<=96) || (int(temp)>=58 && int(temp)<=64)||(int(temp)>=33 && int(temp)<=47)){ 
                t[count]=int(temp);
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                arr[i]=int(temp);
            }
        }
        
    sort(arr,arr+n);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        cout<<char(arr[i])<<" ";
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        cout<<char(t[i])<<" ";
    }
}
```

Get the input as "char" and typecast it to "int".if int value represents a special character then store it in another array .Then perform a sort based on integer values and finally while your printing typecast to "char" again.